# Spark JDBC write to Teradata results in blocked queues

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, teradata, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to write streaming data to Teradata table using `spark.jdbc.write`, this operation is enabling multiple threads on Teradata table which is causing Blocked query situation.

Is there any way to handle multiple threads and make it single thread?

Answer (score 0):

Making writes single-threaded would miss the point of using Spark and will end in a totally inefficient application.

However you could reduce amount of writing threads to achieve efficiency in write operations.

There two steps:

1. Repartition your RDD/DataFrame with lower figure than during processing phase so lesser amount of `cores` could write to Teradata (you could even end with one writing thread per executor if you really want)
2. Suggestion to use Spark connector for Teradata, so you would be able to configure amount of connection threads in a Teradata-recognizable way.

Comment: I'm new to Teradata, is there any way that we can create table in TD which accept  parallel inserts. As spark is initiating multiple threads.

Comment: @user5463155 consider to check this out in Teradata documentation or create a new question on SO.